# Can't send emails to some servers

Tags: php, smtp, timeout, phpmailer

When i try to send emails from my phpmailer class, it returns true, but in the Directadmin mail log it logs a TimeOut.

> 2012-10-21 14:22:14 1TPsca-0000t7-Vj gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
>   [2a00:1450:4013:c01::1a] Connection timed out
>
> 2012-10-21 14:22:14 1TPsca-0000t7-Vj => [Email]
>   F=<[Email]> R=lookuphost T=remote_smtp S=3286
>   H=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [74.125.136.26] X=TLSv1:RC4-SHA:128
>   C="250 2.0.0 OK 1350822120 f43si4569491eem.30"
>
> 2012-10-21 14:22:14 1TPsca-0000t7-Vj Completed

but the email dont got send.

How can i fix this?

Thanks!
Wouter0100

Comment: You need to localise the problem - is it that PHP is failing to queue up the email with the local mail daemon (postfix?) or that it's trying to send it itself (using sockets?) and failing? or perhaps thatthe local mail server accepts the message then fails to send it on? I suspect it's the latter but to track down the problem, try sending an email from the command line. Also, check how phpmailer os configured to actually send the email. Once we know where the problem is, we can begin to diagnose it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connection time-out means the mail server cannot be reached anymore. If the mail server is different from your web server (i.e. not localhost) I'd check with your hosting provider whether they enabled some sort of firewall that blocks connections on the SMTP port

The error that you are receiving means that the connection is failing on this line: SMTP.Connect().

Usually, it means the port is wrong, the server is not up, or you don't have connectivity.

In this case, you don't have connectivity, most likely because your ISP is blocking connection to that remote port.

Try sending the email from your hosted web server.

Even if you could connect, your code won't work as is. Port 465 on Google's SMTP server requires a secure (SSL) connection. You'll still need to implement that.

Gmail's SMTP server requires SSL if I recall correctly.
try this

```
$this->Email->smtpOptions = array(
'port'=>'465', 
'timeout'=>'30',
'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
'username'=>'your_username@gmail.com',
'password'=>'your_gmail_password',
);
```

also 
Read [support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287) - SSL must be used to use the GMail SMTP server. Quote: "If your client does not support SMTP4 authentication, you won't be able to send mail through your client using your Gmail address."